# Can Matlab mark that an axis does not start at zero?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In some fields, it's common to show extra-clearly if the x or y axis does not start at zero by breaking or squiggling the axis. Can this be done in a matlab `plot`?

Example of such an indicator:

[image]

Comment: There are some user-contributed functions on Matlab Answers that do this: [1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45760-break-y-axis), [2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51249-aesethetic-axis-breaks), [3](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22378-break-y-axis?s_tid=srchtitle)